# About to install Ubuntu on a new laptop with Windows 10 and want to be able to re-install Windows in the future

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, backup

I just got a new ThinkPad™ X1 Carbon Gen 7 with Windows 10. I plan to create a bootable USB flash drive and wipe out the Windows OS. Whenever I decide to sell the laptop I would like to be able to restore the preinstalled Windows OS.

Is it possible? I heard about “Bootable USB for all Windows”; is this the correct term I should research?

Do I have to setup Windows before I can do that or is it possible to save time and create a backup (or bootable USB flash drive not sure what's the correct term) without setting up Windows at all?

Comment: When you decide to reinstall Windows, just reinstall Windows, once installed it will automatically be activated.